# Forward multiple domain names to multiple sites

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns, hosting, forwarding

Have searched and viewed many threads, but mostly are about forwarding multiple domains to 1 single site/domain.

What i have now is around 50 domainnames which i have directed to my server ip address.
On my server i use Directadmin.

What i would like is to have the most efficient/easiest way to manage these domainnames and have them forward to (different) sites.

So for example,
Domain1.com, needs to be forwarded to someotherdomain1.com
Domain2.com, needs to be forwarded to someotherdomain2.com
Domain3.com, needs to be forwarded to someotherdomain3.com

What would be the easiest way for me to set something like this up?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these type of rules:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://someotherdomain1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://someotherdomain2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Alternatively if you have access to Apache config then you can utilize [**`RewriteMap`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html) feature and have just one single rule here like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([^.]+)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://${domainMap:%1}.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

In your **Apache config** you need to define `domainMap` as:

```
RewriteMap domainMap txt://path/to/domain-map.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much anubhava! Working perfectly